# CSS to target a class with a specific attributes value

Tags: html, css

On inspecting a webpage, I found an HTML element of interest, and looked at its css style properties below.

```
.Node-bullet:before {
    font-family: "IcoMoon", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    content: "\e90d";
}
```

I am trying to use stylish (chrome plugin) to overwrite that CSS.

```
.Node-bullet:before[content="\e90d"]{
    content: none !important;   
}
```

Its not working unfortunately. Is there a way to specifically search for a CSS class with an existing attribute`[content]`, filter its value `[\e90d]`, and overwrite it?

I know this is not efficient for production-level sites, I'm simply modifying my notetaking app client-side. I've tried looking at other selectors like descendent but I can't seem to find an easy pattern

**EDIT**

Overall HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="Node-self">
  <div class="Node-bullet">
  ::before <!-- SELECT THIS -->
  ::after
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Node-self is-collapsed">
  <div class="Node-bullet">
  ::before <!--DO NOT SELECT THIS -->
  ::after
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Content is not actually an attribute to the element. If it were, you would be able to select using it. Having said that, I do not see any reason why the selector `.Node-bullet:before` shouldn't work fine in this case.

Comment: what is `content` called then

Comment: @Kagerjay It is a CSS property.

Comment: `.Node-bullet:before{
    content: none !important;   
}`  can you please ry this.

Comment: @msz I have that already, but I'm trying to not target the same CSS class with a different `content` value

Comment: If you want to target only this particular pseudo element and no others, maybe you can use the `nth-child` pseudo class for specificity.

Comment: it doesn't follow any nth-child patterns though unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

[content](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp) is a property, [before](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) a selector: you can not mix them.

For example you can find all anchor with attribute target _blank, but not with  specific "content" or "background".

```
a[target=_blank] {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the specific answer to this problem, but the answer to the overall issue I had using a NOT with a descendent selector

```
.Node-self:not(.is-collapsed)>.Node-bullet:before{
    content: none !important;
}
```